# jboss-eap-6.x adding infinispan indexing element from jboss-cli

Tags: jboss6.x, infinispan, jboss-cli

I would like to know the commat to insert into jboss-cli to add ti a infinispan distrubuted cache the element indexing: i want my standalone looks like this

`<cache-container name="container" default-cache="sessions" jndi-name="java:jboss/infinispan/container/container" start="EAGER">
                <transport stack="tcp" lock-timeout="60000"/>
                <distributed-cache name="sessions" mode="ASYNC" start="EAGER" batching="true">
                    <expiration max-idle="3600000" interval="900000"/>
                    <indexing index="LOCAL"/>
                </distributed-cache>
            </cache-container>`

but i cannot find any command to add the indexing element, so i can only provide this

```html
<transport stack="tcp" lock-timeout="60000"/>
                <distributed-cache name="sessions" mode="ASYNC" start="EAGER" batching="true">
                    <expiration max-idle="3600000" interval="900000"/>       
                </distributed-cache>
                <distributed-cache name="sessions-id" mode="ASYNC" start="EAGER" batching="true">
                    <expiration max-idle="3600000" interval="900000"/>
                </distributed-cache>
            </cache-container>
```

using this

```
/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=container/:add(default-cache=sessions, jndi-name=java:jboss/infinispan/container/container, start=EAGER)
/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=container/transport=TRANSPORT/:add(lock-timeout=60000, stack=tcp)
reload
/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=container/distributed-cache=spid-sessions/:add(mode=ASYNC,start=EAGER,batching=true)
/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=container/distributed-cache=sessions/expiration=EXPIRATION:add(max-idle=3600000,interval=900000)
```

what can i do? thanks

Comment: i founded, i need to add indexing=LOCAL when i add the distributed cache, i though that it was a new element to add like expiration

/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=container/distributed-cache=sessions/:add(mode=ASYNC,start=EAGER,batching=true,indexing=LOCAL)

Comment: please write this as a proper answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i founded, i need to add indexing=LOCAL when i add the distributed cache, i though that it was a new element to add like expiration /subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=container/distributed-cache=sessions/:add(‌​mode=ASYNC,start=EAGER,batching=true,indexing=LOCAL) –